# How do I upgrade Ubuntu Jaunty to the current Ubuntu release?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04

I tried following the instructions described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/Jaunty

However, this gives me the following error:

```
root@hawk:~# do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Done Upgrade tool signature
Done Upgrade tool
Done downloading            
extracting 'lucid.tar.gz'
authenticate 'lucid.tar.gz' against 'lucid.tar.gz.gpg' 
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

An upgrade from 'jaunty' to 'lucid' is not supported with this tool. 

root@hawk:~#
```

How can I do this safely?

Comment: And you really did a `sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude safe-upgrade` before?

Answer (score 1):

I always did it through changing the repositories : Don't forget the -i below.

```
   sed -i 's/jaunty/lucid/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

    aptitude update
    aptitude upgrade
    aptitude dist-upgrade
```